# Why is there a black line appearing on image loaded to UIImage, that doesn't exist in the source file?

Tags: ios, swift, image, uikit, uiimage

I am trying to load images into an iOS application that are downloaded from a server. I have encountered an issue where a thin black line is appearing on the far right of the image when it's loaded using `UIImage(contentsOf:)` or an equivalent UIImage initialiser. I initially thought this was an error in my URLSession code, but I have since been able to reproduce this locally with a file that I've created in Affinity Designer.

The image is a little odd - it uses the "Grey" color model, and the "Generic Grey Gamma 2.2 Profile". It also has a resolution of 319 x 350. If I switch to an RGB profile the problem appears to go away, and if I change the dimensions, the problem also goes away. This can occur with images I've created with this configuration, as well as the source image from the server.

[image: Source image]

The source image is solid white, however once I load it as a UIImage, the column of pixels on the far right has a thin black line that has appeared out of nowhere. I also tried CIImage and loading directly as a CGImage, and the same issue occurs, but I imagine it's all using the same underlying image IO code?

[image: UIImage]

Bare in mind the UIImage attached here is via the quick look feature in Xcode, but I checked for the line of black pixels in code and they are there.

I can only seem to reproduce this on my physical device, whereas the simulator works as expected.

This is the block of code I'm using to load the source image above from stack overflow, and then check if it's entirely white (which it should be).

```swift
//Load the image from stack overflow.
guard let url = URL(string: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymCX5.jpg"),
      let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
      let image = UIImage(data: data),
      let cgImage = image.cgImage
else {
    print("Unable to load image")
    return
}

//Get the pixel data.
guard let pixelData = cgImage.dataProvider?.data,
      let data = CFDataGetBytePtr(pixelData)
else {
    print("Unable to get data from cgimage")
    return
}

//Check there is on byte per pixel. If there's not, then the for loop
//below won't work as expected.
let byteCount = CFDataGetLength(pixelData)
let width = cgImage.width
let height = cgImage.height

print("Byte count: byteCount")
guard byteCount == (width * height) else {
    print("More than one byte per pixel")
    return
}

//Loop over each pixel and find any value that isn't white (255).
for byteOffset in 0..<byteCount {
    if data[byteOffset] != 255 {
        print("Found a non-white pixel \(data[byteOffset]) at X: \((byteOffset % width) + 1), Y: \((byteOffset / width) + 1)")
    }
}
```

And the output...

```
Found a non-white pixel 254 at X: 316, Y: 1
Found a non-white pixel 254 at X: 317, Y: 1
Found a non-white pixel 1 at X: 318, Y: 1
Found a non-white pixel 0 at X: 319, Y: 1
...etc
```

Has anyone seen this before? Does anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: Quick suggestion, you should use data task instead of Data(contentsOf: url) while loading the remote resource [refer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1413892-init) as it will block the main thread.
Can you check this,  Instead of putting it on UIIMage and then reading the data just read the Data taken from the URL content and print it?

Comment: Yes, `URLSession` is always a better way to fetch data from a remote source. But, no, simply printing the compressed raw JPG asset is unlikely to be helpful in diagnosing what is going on (unless you dive into the JPG spec and manually verify, byte-by-byte, that it has been encoded correctly, which is a non-trivial exercise). This pixel buffer routine is fine way of diagnosing that this particular JPG is not being decoded properly. The question is where to go from here: Filing a [bug report](https://developer.apple.com/bug-reporting/) is probably warranted, at this point.

Comment: Yes, I get the same results either way.

Thanks @Rob. I have reported it as an issue with Apple.